# How can I copy the values from My java class to a JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I Have successfully moved the values from my Data.xml to Java class and I tested it by getting the values to Eclipse console . But I am unable to copy the values from java class to my JPA class. Am I missing something? ANy suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {


        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Service.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();


        File XMLfile = new File( "C:\\Users\\Data.xml");

        Service Serv = (Service) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);
        System.out.println(model.toString());

        MyComponent MyComp = new MyComponent();
        JPAComponent JPAcomp = new JPAComponent();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(JPACom, MyComp);
```

Comment: what JPA class? what "Java class" ? Is anybody reading this missing something? because it makes nothing clear about what you are doing

Comment: Hi Billy. thanks for your reply I just figured out the answer to my problem.

Comment: I apologize for not being so clear.